Should it be possible for effective batch size and real batch size to produce different results?
I think I have observed a situation where effective batch size is performing better than actual batch size.
Here are some details of what I'm doing. I'm finetuning Llama 3 8B using Hugging Face in a Colab notebook. I initially used a batch size of 2 with gradient accumulation steps 4 to give an effective batch size of 8.
Then I realized I could fit a bigger batch into the GPUs memory so I set batch size to 8 and gradient accumulation steps to 1. However this made my performance worse.
At first I thought I must have done something, however after creating a duplicate notebook and changing only parameters batch size and       gradient accumulation steps while keeping effective batch size constant, I found there really is a difference.
You don't have to read the notebook, but just as proof, here is a notebook with per_device_train_batch_size = 2 and gradient_accumulation_steps = 4.
And here is exactly the same notebook with the only difference being per_device_train_batch_size = 8 and gradient_accumulation_steps = 1.
If you scroll to the bottom you will find the Exact Match score evaluation is different.
How is this possible?
